# How to track external URL clicks from SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, auditing

I've been asked to track how many times an outside URL is clicked from a SharePoint 2007 page (listed in a links library).

I'd like to do this from the page itself if possible.  Site auditing has been enabled but that only seems to capture document access, etc and not the specific URL).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a blank page with a single i-frame to display the outside URL.  Users can then run the canned site usage report to see who accessed the page when.